# Como sinalizar um Plágio?

Tags: debate, sinalização, plágio

Recentemente me deparei com essa situação. O sujeito pegou minha resposta inteira, adicionou muito pouco ou quase nada. Na verdade nada que importe para o código funcionar corretamente e publicou como nova resposta...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**A minha intenção era sinalizar como plágio, pois eu entendo como tal, porém não existe essa opção. Como devemos reportar esse tipo de atitude?**

[Como centralizar e posicionar lado a lado duas imagens? html css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333270/como-centralizar-e-posicionar-lado-a-lado-duas-imagens-html-css)

Comment: Sinaliza pra moderacao e explica o que ocorreu, eles irão analisar.

Answer (score 7):

## Investigue

Geralmente, para poder identificar se a  resposta que está parecida com a minha ou com outra, eu uso a técnica de olhar o horário em que a resposta foi publicada.

Pode haver casos em que, por coincidência, as pessoas postaram com 1 minuto ou 30 segundos de diferença e os códigos acabam ficando parecidos. Nesses casos, é melhor deixar rolar ou um dos envolvidos ter a iniciativa de remover a resposta, pra não ter duplicidade ou redundância.

No seu caso, é perceptível que a resposta foi feita com pelo menos 20 minutos de diferença. Nesse caso, eu considero que a pessoa teve tempo o suficiente para poder ver a pergunta, ver as respostas que já foram dadas e ponderar sobre o que responder.

Além do mais, conforme a imagem mostra, os códigos foram copiados em mínimos detalhes.

No caso, digo que sinalize, para a moderação avaliar se há ou não má intenção da parte de quem fez isso.

O que eu citei antes sobre a "técnica no tempo" é apenas para não cairmos na situação de "acusar sem provas".

Eu diria que é sempre bom tentar resolver com a pessoa primeiro antes de sinalizar, mas é claro, isso depende do usuário. Usuários com histórico de mal comportamento eu nem perco tempo.

Ou seja, tente deixar um comentário, como você fez, para ver se o usuário toma uma posição.

Além do mais, pode ser que o Autor da Resposta também tenha clicado na opção `"Copiar o código para nova resposta"` e publicou ansiosamente antes de editar.

Aí teria que avaliar se ele publicou e deixou pra lá (
sem adicionar mais informações, digo), ou se ele copiou, publicou e alterou logo em seguida, apenas para ter "uma base".

Eu mesmo costumo copiar alguns trechos para modificar, quando isso torna fácil o complemento que vou fazer.

Em resumo: Sempre tente presumir a boa intenção. Creio que um posicionamento [ou não] da pessoa que copiou possa ficar evidente se você fizer um comentário falando sobre o assunto.

Se a pessoa se justificar positivamente, tudo bem. Oriente-a a consertar o que está errado. Se negativamente, sinalize para a moderação.

## O seu caso

Pelo que vi no caso específico, é melhor sinalizar mesmo. O Autor da Resposta não reconheceu que fez errado ao você questionar e foi irredutível nos comentários.

Nesses casos, deixa a moderação resolver

Comment: Legal vc responder Wallace. Logo que eu vi a resposta dele assumo que fiquei meio irritado, mas logo o questionei sobre porque copiar a resposta etc. Nesse meio tempo a própria comunidade negativou a resposta dela a ponto dele preferir remove-la antes que eu sinaliza-se. Mas vou te falar uma coisa que me deixou pensativo! Ao entrar no perfil do cisadão e ver a foto de perfil dele, me pareceu ser uma pessoa que pode ser que tenha algum tipo de problema de visão... Se isso for de fato, e se ele usa leitor de tela, pode ser que esse leitor não reconheça uma imagem sem width e sem heigth...

Comment: [continuando]: Talvez seja por isso que ele falou que não funcionava, já que eu usei uma imagem indexada por CDN e que não tem um valor explícito para width e heigth... Isso não justifica o fato dele não ter creditado da onde ele pegou parte ou a totalidade do código. Mas pode indicar um problema que muitas vezes passa despercebido aqui, que é a acessibilidade do código que postamos como resposta... Isso me deixou pensativo....

Comment: Uma observação: "técnica do tempo" geralmente funciona, mas não é 100%. Eu mesmo já comecei uma resposta, parei por algum motivo (pra almoçar, por exemplo) e só terminei um tempo depois. @hugocsl mesmo que ele tenha o motivo da acessibilidade para justificar seu plágio, poderia ser adicionado em um comentário, não acho necessário uma nova resposta por um detalhe. Apesar de ser importante, a acessibilidade é detalhe para a maioria dos casos, principalmente para quem está iniciando e não se preocupa sequer com compatibilidade entre navegadores. Não estou dizendo que esse é o caso, mas no geral é

Comment: Além disso, o respondedor precisa ser o mais claro e completo possível, explicar o porque, não simplesmente dizer que adicionou duas propriedades à tag. Do modo como ficou a resposta, parecia que é algo supérfluo, quase redundante

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam realmente em alguns casos o tempo pode não ser um indicativo 100% garantido. No caso de ser um detalhe ele realmente poderia apenas ter comentado na minha própria resposta, mas talvez até por falta de experiencia no site ele tenha feito uma resposta nova... Mas o fato de nem se quer citar ou comentar que pegou o código da outra resposta realmente é algo que precisamos analisar, pois ao meu ver não é uma conduta legal...

Comment: Se você parou pra almoçar, acho que o mínimo que deve fazer antes de voltar a editar, é  verificar se alguém já respondeu.